# SQLAlchemy subqueries ,do they apply in this scenario

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have been reading a lot about SQLAlchemy subqueries and somehow i think somehow it applies to my problem .

I have the following 2 queries

```
Query 1=>isp_ratings_per_service = db.session.query(func.count(Ratings.ratings_value).label('count_of_users'),
                                               func.sum(Ratings.ratings_value).label('sum_of_ratings'),
                                               func.avg(Ratings.ratings_value).label('avg_of_ratings'),
                                               Isps.isp_name, Service_metric.metric_name, Services.service_name) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.isp_id == Isps.isp_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.ratings_value == Ratings.ratings_value) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.metric_id == Service_metric.metric_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.user_id == User.user_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric_ratings.service_id == Services.service_id) \
        .filter(Service_metric.metric_name == metric_name) \
        .filter(Services.service_name == service_name) \
        .group_by(Isps.isp_name)

Query 2 => ratings_table_values = db.session.query(Ratings.rating_value, Ratings.rating_comment)
```

I want to use the values stored in this line

```
func.avg(Service_metric_ratings.ratings_id).label('avg_of_ratings'),
```

to select data in another table based on this value like this

```
for i in isp_ratings_per_service:
    (round(i.avg_of_ratings)))
    ratings_table_values = Ratings.query.filter_by(rating_value=(round(i.avg_of_ratings)))
```

is it possible to put them in one query using a subquery ,the problem at the moment is that it creates 2 iterations in the flask template which is not giving me the results i want as below

```
 {% for i in ratings_table_values %}
 <tr>
  <td>{{ i.rating_value}}</td>
  <td>{{ i.rating_comment}}</td>
 {% endfor %}

{% for i in isp_ratings_per_service %}
blah blah blah
{% endfor %}
```

I would prefer if one query would give me the results i want ,

Comment: It looks like you need to do a join to `Ratings`. You seem to be summing and averaging IDs of `Ratings` instead of the `rating_value` column in the `Ratings` table.

Comment: @univerio yes you are right , i have edited my query accordingly , i gues it was working because ratings_id and rating_value had the same value....the difference was that the ratings_id was the primary key so i got rid of that column and made the rating_value the primary key for that table

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my own question like this , the queries are seperate with no need for Joins and its working perfectly. I have developed my logic in Jinja

```
{% for i in isp_ratings_per_service %}
  <td>{{ i.isp_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.metric_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.service_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.count_of_users }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.sum_of_ratings }}</td>
  <td>{{ i.avg_of_ratings|round|int }}</td>
         {% for m in ratings_table_values %}
            {% if (m.ratings_value) ==(i.avg_of_ratings|round|int)%}
                 <td>{{ m.ratings_comment}}</td>
            {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% else %}
  <tr><td colspan="7"><em>No entries here so far</em></td></tr>
  {% endfor %}
```